# How to determine free/used space of an unmounted xfs partition?

Tags: filesystems, xfs

I can determine an unmounted partition of ext4 with tune2fs, but I don't know how to do it with an xfs partition, I wonder if it's that right:

```
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdb5
465567744
# blockdev  --getbsz /dev/sdb5
4096


# xfs_db -c "freesp -s"  /dev/sdb5 | sed  -n -r  's/(total free blocks )(.*)/\2/p)
35981
```

So, I calculate the used space in MB so:

```
# bc -q
35981*4096
147378176
last/1024/1024
140
465567744/1024/1024
444
444-140
304
```

It results in 304 MB

However if I mount the partition, it shows:

```
df -h /dev/sdb5
S.ficheros     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
/dev/sdb5        441M   323M  118M  74% /xfs
```

There are 19MB of difference, why?

Comment: if your purpose is to know free/used space without mount it, just use `gparted`

Comment: Doesn't `xfs` have 5% reserved space (by default)? https://www.spinics.net/lists/xfs/msg30776.html